# LangChain output not being passed to MessagingResponse

Tags: flask, amazon-ec2, twilio, ngrok, langchain

In my Twilio WhatsApp chatbot, I successfully pass the input and obtain a string object, which ultimately doesn't pass into the MessagingResponse.

Using Flask to render this chatbot on an AWS EC2 instance.

Here's my code for the chatbot:

```
# Define a route to handle incoming requests
@app.route('/chatgpt', methods=['POST'])
def chatgpt():
    incoming_que = request.values.get('Body', '').lower()
    print("Question: ", incoming_que)
    answer = generate_answer(incoming_que)
    print("BOT Answer: ", answer)
    bot_resp = MessagingResponse()
    message = bot_resp.message()
    message.body(answer)
    # Return the response as a string
    return str(bot_resp)

# Run the Flask app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False, port=5000)
```

An `answer` that I get is the following:

> Title: A Trip to Spain: Exploring Malaga and Barcelona
>
> Day 1
>
> Summary: Visit the Picasso Museum and the Alcazaba Fortress in Malaga.
>
> Location: Malaga, Spain
>
> Places:
>
> 1. Picasso Museum
>
> 2. Alcazaba Fortress

However nothing passes into body, and as a result, I don't get a status 200 on my `ngrok`.

[image]

I have tried using another chatbot such as this:

```
def generate_answer(question):
    model_engine = "text-davinci-002"
    prompt = (f"Q: {question}\n"
              "A:")

    response = openai.Completion.create(
        engine=model_engine,
        prompt=prompt,
        max_tokens=1024,
        n=1,
        stop=None,
        temperature=0.7,
    )

    answer = response.choices[0].text.strip()
    return answer


# Define a route to handle incoming requests
@app.route('/chatgpt', methods=['POST'])
def chatgpt():
    incoming_que = request.values.get('Body', '').lower()
    print("Question: ", incoming_que)
    # Generate the answer using GPT-3
    answer = generate_answer(incoming_que)
    print("BOT Answer: ", answer)
    bot_resp = MessagingResponse()
    msg = bot_resp.message()
    msg.body(answer)
    return str(bot_resp)


# Run the Flask app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False, port=5000)
```

Which worked perfectly and I get a status 200 response.

I am thinking my output may be not XML compatible. I tried passing just a simple "Hi" into the msg.body, and that didn't work either. Not sure why I can't pass anything into my MessagingResponse().